# Can't import Python libraries in Windows cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, anaconda

I'm running Python on Windows, installed through Anaconda, using the cmd as:

```
C:\path\to\anaconda>python
```

I cannot importlibraries, for instance `import numpy as np` fails. When I run Spyder, however, I am able to import these libraries.

Comment: That implies that this `python` command runs a different interpreter from what you have in Spyder. Run `where.exe python` to see the executable it's finding.

Comment: @ErykSun `where.exe python` returns `C:\path\to\anaconda>python` when I'm in this directory. Otherwise, it returns an error.

Comment: @ToniAz: try `C:\path\to\anaconda>pip install numpy`. It'll try to install numpy in the python you get when you run it from the command prompt.

A better way is to create virtual environments (with `python - venv` or `mkvirtualenv`) and install your packages on those environments.

Comment: In Spyder, run `import sys; print(sys.executable)` to see what it's using.

Comment: @ErykSun it returns `C:\path\to\anaconda\pythonw`. Note the extra 'w'. Also note that `print(sys.path)` returns extra directories when typed in Spyder, in particular `C:\path\to\python\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions` and `C:\path\.ipython`.

Comment: In Spyder, check `import numpy; print(numpy.__file__)`.

Comment: @ErykSun It returns `C:\path\to\python\\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py`

Answer (score 0):

At the window command prompt run either 'dir /s python*.exe' or 'where python.exe'. If 2 python installs are on system then remove 1. For the python install that you keep, make sure the python*._pth file has all directories needed for .py files to access. It is usually drive : python_install \ python*._pth.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this worked

1. Start Menu > Edit system environment paths > Environment variables
2. Under system variables, click Path, then click Edit
3. Add the following paths:

- C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
- C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts
- C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin

Note: Maybe you need to edit the location of your Anaconda folder. To do this, go to python (i.e. in your IDE) and do this to get the location

```
import sys
import os
os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
```